# Globalization of HTML controls

Tags: asp.net, html, globalization

How can i implement globalization in html control

like for ex:

for asp.net control i can do

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" meta:resourcekey="Button1" />
        <!-- Explicit Localization -->
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text = "<%$ Resources:Sample_aspx, Button1Caption %>"/>
```

how do i achieve this in a html control like a label or html anchor tag

Comment: I don't even know ASP, but doesn't `<label><%$ Resources:Sample_aspx, LabelCaption %></label>` work?

Comment: Hahahahahaha I laughed so hard. Hate when that happens :)

Answer (score 3):

You could probably do it a number of ways...The first one would be to add the `runat="server"` control which turns any regular control into a server control

or perhaps use the localization control. Here's a sample from the [MSDN article on localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228093%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
<h1>
   <asp:localize runat="server" 
       Text="<%$ Resources:WebResources, WelcomeMessage %>" />
</h1>
```

This would grab the value from your resource file and put in in a `h1` tag which is just regular html

That link also has some other pretty useful information to your problem...